# llenar JCombobox de java swing con un array de objetos

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, arraylist

he estado intentando llenar un combobox de java swing con un array de objetos, he intentado varias cosas en internet pero no he llegado al resultado, les dejo un pantallazo de algo que intenté, aún soy estudiante así que agradeceré su respuesta, la idea es que el combobox tenga todos los objetos que me entregó la bd, y que agregué a un arraylist.

```
private void formInternalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                         
    ControladorCliente cc = new ControladorCliente();
    ArrayList<ClienteDireccion> lista = cc.listarDirecciones();
    comboDireccion = new JComboBox(lista);
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún mensaje de error? Intenta con `toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

El JComboBox necesita ser parametrizado para que funcione correctamente.
La parametrizacion sirve para identificar correctamente los elementos dentro del combobox, en tu caso seria de la siguiente forma: `JComboBox<ClienteDireccion> comboDireccion = new JComboBox<ClienteDireccion>(lista);`